# How can I get my ad banner to the bottom of my application?

Tags: java, android, ads, adview

I'm trying to get my ad banner to the bottom of my screen, but it keeps on showing up in the middle of the screen, here's a picture of what it looks like: http://i.gyazo.com/8e5e79219bb7e03a757778b8c13d9cd6.png

Here's my .Java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton btnSwitch;

private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;
MediaPlayer mp;

private AdView adView;

/* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3642697202265316/5249422388";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    layout.addView(adView);



    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    // flash switch button
    btnSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);


    // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not        
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        // device doesn't support flash
        // Show alert message and close the application
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // closing the application
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();

        return;


    }

    // get the camera
    getCamera();

    // displaying button image
    toggleButtonImage();


    // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
    btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // turn off flash
                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                // turn on flash
                turnOnFlash();
            }
        }
    });
}



// Get the camera
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

 // Turning On flash
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}

// Turning Off flash
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}


 // Playing sound
 // will play button toggle sound on flash on / off
private void playSound(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_off);
    }else{
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_on);
    }
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }
    }); 
    mp.start();
}

/*
 * Toggle switch button images
 * changing image states to on / off
 * */
private void toggleButtonImage(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_switch_on);
    }else{
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_switch_off);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
          adView.pause();
        }
    super.onPause();
    // on pause turn off the flash
    turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // on resume turn on the flash
    if(hasFlash)
        turnOnFlash();
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.resume();
      }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // on starting the app get the camera params
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // on stop release the camera
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();   //or getActionBar()
    actionBar.hide();

}

private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

protected void onResume1() {
    super.onResume();
    // .... other stuff in my onResume ....
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back Again To Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Any help? Thanks.

```
    <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:keepScreenOn = "true"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/radial_background"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_switch_on"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@null"/>


   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post `activity_main` xml

Comment: Just added it to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change your **Linear Layout** to **Relative Layout**. If you change you can get some of the properties from **Relative Layout** eg: "**align parent center**" or "**align parent bottom**" that properties will solve your design view. Hope for help.

For your code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)adView.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
adView.setLayoutParams(params);
```